# Flutter stream builders concept

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

I have a map in which i store key and value pair. I have put this map in a stream, which we will call dataStream for ease.

now i have a stream builder, this stream-builder uses dataStream. I want this stream builder to build only if a specific key's value is altered.

Currently my stream builder responds to any change in the map. I want to instruct it to change only when a certain key's value in the map changes. Is this possible in stream builder and how?

```
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: dataBloc.dataStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if(snapshot.hasData){
     Map<String, String> dataMap = snapshot.data;
     // some logic
     }
     return widget;
     }
```

**I want to see if a specific key's value in this map changes, only then rebuild my existing widget else, leave it as it is. Do not build it again**

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to filter for specific events using `where`:

```
stream: dataBloc.dataStream.where((item) => /* check criteria */ item['key'] == 'foo')
```

Comment: Do i access the map which is inside my dataStream using snapshot.data ? I am not sure how to access it in the where clause;

Comment: I see. Didn't recognize this is about Firebase. `item` is the same what `snapshot.data` returns in `builder: ...`

Comment: I have one more question, what happens if my where clause is false; Will it rebuild? Ideally i want it to rebuild if there is a change in the output of the where clause!

Comment: for example, if the condition is satisfied build, if it is not satisfied build but differently.

Comment: If the where clause is false, the event will be filtered and not passed to the listener (StreamBuilder), so no, it's as if the event were never sent.

Comment: "if there is a change in the output of the where clause!" sorry, but I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184893/discussion-between-gopro-and-gunter-zochbauer).